# How do you use send_query of the PG::Connection class in the Ruby pg gem?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, postgresql, query-optimization, pg

How do you use the public instance method `send_query` of the `PG::Connection` class in the Ruby pg gem?

Can it help speed up the execution time of a program like this?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,...,100000]  # elements in no specific order
conn = PG.connect(OMITTED)
conn.transaction do |conn|
  a.each do |i]
    conn.exec("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES ($1)",[i])
  end
end
```

**Hypothesis**: If I don't wait for the result, then I can keep sending queries to the PostgreSQL server and finish sooner.

**Experiment**: Rewritten version:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
conn = PG.connect(OMITTED)
conn.setnonblocking(true)
conn.transaction do |conn|
  a.each do |i]
    conn.send_query("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES ($1)",[i])
  end
end
```

**Result**: No difference in running time.

Some additional questions:

- Is my assumption correct?
- Is this necessarily a job for threads?
- Am I supposed to handle the output from exec somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried joining all SQL inserts into one? In my experiment it's faster:

```
require "rubygems"
require "pg"

a = (0...10000).sort_by(&:rand)  # elements in no specific order
conn = PG.connect(:dbname => "numbers")
t = Time.now
conn.transaction do |conn|
  a.each do |i|
    conn.exec("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES ($1)",[i])
  end
end
p Time.now - t

t = Time.now
conn.transaction do |conn|
  conn.exec(
    a.map { |i|
      "INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (%d);" % i
    }.join("")
  )
end
p Time.now - t

#=> 2.658903, 0.572997
```

Comment: I like the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I don't actually store the data to insert as an array.  If I stored it, I would probably run out of memory. I have millions of inserts.

Comment: Just split your data into chunks N records each